# .NET Graph API is not returning all child folders of Outlook mailbox

Tags: c#, .net

I've a class that uses a `GraphServiceClient` instance as `_graphClient` member. The method in question is the following:

```cs
public async Task<string?> GetInboxSubFolderIdAsync(string email, string folderName)
{
    var inbox = await _graphClient.Users[email].MailFolders["inbox"].GetAsync(x => {
        x.QueryParameters.Expand = new[] { "childFolders" };
    });

    var folder = inbox?.ChildFolders?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DisplayName.EqualsIgnoreCase(folderName));

    return folder?.Id;
}
```

The inbox contains 40 subfolders and this is noticeable inspecting the `inbox.ChildFoldersCount`.

Anyway `inbox.ChildFolders` contains only 10 elements.

I tried a direct HTTP call with `$top` parameter and I'm able to get all the elements. **Is there a way to pass this parameter with .NET Graph API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
async Task<string?> GetInboxSubFolderIdAsync(string email, string folderName)
{
    var response = await _graphClient.Users[email].MailFolders["inbox"].ChildFolders.GetAsync(x =>
    {
        x.QueryParameters.Filter = $"displayName eq '{folderName}'";
    });

    return response?.Value?.FirstOrDefault()?.Id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**